# Java Random Double Array from -50 to 50

Tags: java, random

I need to populate an array with random numbers from -50 to 50 and need to use Math.random(). Here is my current code:

```
double[] randomNums = new double[5];

for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {
    randomNums[i] = 100 * Math.random() - 50;
}
for (double i: randomNums) {
    System.out.println(i + ',');
}
```

Output:

```
-5.836717454677796,
44.07635593282988,
23.650145270722884,
93.00810678750743,
54.0536237451922
```

Why is this going above 50?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding the value of the char `,`, which has value 44 to each double. You can test this using:

```
System.out.println(0 + ',');
```

Output: `44`

To fix this you can simply remove the `+ ','`

Comment: Or using `","` instead of `','`.

Comment: Or use `+ ","` which concats a "," string instead of adding the char value